# What implementation of heap does Java use?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, heap

[Wikipedia on Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) lists down many implementations of heap. I was thinking as to what implementation does Java use for heap?

Is the decision kept on the JVM vendors or it is specified in JVM specification as to what implementation should be used?

Comment: It uses a Java heap -- one that meets the requirements set out in the JVM spec.  Some believe that the Java heap is always a copying heap, but this is not true.  And the above reference is not really about heaps in this sense -- it's really about keeping a freespace tree, and most Java implementations don't do that, at least not for the main parts of the heap.  (The ["dynamic memory allocation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation) article is closer to the point.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of them. The heap in the Wiki entry you cited is a binary tree-based sorting data structure. The heap used by the JVM is a dynamic memory area. The Wiki-type is implemented by java.util.Heap, not by the JVM's heap. I know it's confusing  but there it is. Note that the Wiki entry has a disambiguating note at the top.

Answer (score 1):

The heap type is a decision of the JVM implementor. The [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) on heaps gives no indication as to a required or preferred type of heap.